# Entity getOwner()

Tags: 8, entities

In what table does an entity "foo" get its metadata stored? In Drupal 7, there are tables for all the fields for a content type and the node table had some metadata stored, but most data for a content type were in other tables. I think I understand that configuration is what metadata is required for an entity. But I cannot figure out which tables would store an association between node/100 and user/10. Using breakpoints I'm trying to troubleshoot where in the node object this info resides and try to deduce its definitions to backtrack where metadata like author/owner is stored.

Comment: This is a base field referencing the user entity, since D8.7 standardized in a trait [EntityOwnerTrait::ownerBaseFieldDefinitions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21EntityOwnerTrait.php/function/EntityOwnerTrait%3A%3AownerBaseFieldDefinitions/8.7.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8 all that stuff is stored as YAML files in your config directory.

If you don't have a custom path to that directory it's usually located in `sites/default/files/config......` where .. is a long randomly generated hash key.

There you will find config files for all entities and fields and configuration settings.

**EDIT:** To get a node's asociation with it's author you'll have to look in the `node_field_data` table, the UID field there is the author's user ID.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Running vendor/bin/drush cex I see the dump of all current config. Searching for a string of either "100" or a partial of the UUID for node/100 ("55b1372d-9ec2-4a4d-b878-") returns no such data. Searching the config table for any mention of this node returns no data. There's something in the db to make the association of an instance of a node with its author, and other node metadata?

Comment: Try to look at my edit